# wiki dump encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, wiki, dump, wikimedia-dumps

I'm using WikiPrep to process the latest wiki dump enwiki-20121101-pages-articles.xml.bz2.  Instead of "use Parse::MediaWikiDump;" I replaced that by "use MediaWiki::DumpFile::Compat;" and did the proper changes in the code. Then, I ran

```
perl wikiprep.pl -f enwiki-20121101-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

I got an error

```
enwiki-20121101-pages-articles.xml.bz2:1: parser error : Document is empty
BZh91AY&SY±H¦ÂOÿ~Ð`ÿÿÿ¿ÿÿÿ¿ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ½ÿýþdß8õEnÞ¶zëJ¨Eà®mEÓP|f÷Ô
^
```

I guess there are some non-utf8 characters contained in the dump. So I ran

```
iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 enwiki-20121101-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

And indeed, I got some errors

```
BZh91AY&SYiconv: illegal input sequence at position 10
```

So, my question is what's the encoding format of wiki dump and if I wish to convert it to utf-8, what shall I do? Or how should modify wikiprep.pl to avoid such problems.

Many thanks

-- [solved] I should first unzip the file first.

Comment: You are running iconv on the compressed (bz2) version of the file, rather than the XML file itself.

Comment: hi, borrible 2. Thanks very much. Indeed, I should unzip the file first. I got it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You are running iconv on the compressed (bz2) version of the file, rather than the XML file itself. Uncompress it first.

(Posting borrible's answer so that this resolved question is not listed as unanswered.)